# Navbar gets cropped HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navbar gets cropped and I can't seem to figure out why.
I'll include this code snippet to a codepen since the code is quite large.
personally I think something is going wrong in this part:

```
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(#2b1055, #7597de);
}
```

Not quite sure though.
[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/MdeG/pen/NWjWXWZ).

Comment: Have you tried `min-height: calc(100vh - 60px)` *60px* being the top and bottom padding on your header?

Answer (score 0):

The cropping issue is coming from the styles you have assigned to the `*` selector:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden; // specifically this line
}
```

Settting any styles to the `*` selector is generally not approved of as it will surely cause numerous mutations down the CSS tree that aren't intended.

That said, if you remove the `overflow-x: hidden` statement from the `*` selector you should see the cropping is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

section
{
   z-index:-1;
  min-width:100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(#2b1055, #7597de);
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;

    display: flex;
      justify-content: right;

    z-index: 4;
}

header .logo
{
  width:20%;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 70;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
header ul
{
  width:80%;
  z-index: 5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

header ul li
{
  z-index:6;
    list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;


}
```

This stops the cropping issue but you still have to do your personal padding.